# nginx how can I rewrite a location

Tags: nginx

I want http://localhost/health  ->  http://localhost/health.html , 
how can I write my location config?

this is my location ,but It does not work.

```
location ^~  /health {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  health.html ;
}

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `rewrite` directive.

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    rewrite ^/heath/?$ /health.html? break;
}
```

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite